# Context: Hanging (outdented) figure caption

Tags: captions, context

I want to recreate a caption similar to the following:

```
Figure 1. Here is my caption text that
    wraps underneath the figure label.
```

And here a typeset example:

[image: Example typeset caption. The second line onwards is indented compared to the first. The Caption label is still part of the text, not separate.]

I've seen this answer: [Is it possible to align caption and caption text of figure(table) separately in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521563/is-it-possible-to-align-caption-and-caption-text-of-figuretable-separately-in/522242#522242) that places the caption wholly separate to the label. But I'm not sure how to modify to get what I want.

My initial idea was to use `\startnarrower` and `\stopnarrower` with a negative indent, but I'm not sure how to apply this to a caption.

Comment: I've added an image example. The second line onwards is indented compared to the first, but the caption label is still part of the main text and not in a separate column (as ends up in the link I included).

Comment: There is a `hang` option for float captions but this moves the whole counter to the left of the text block. What you're trying can be achieved with a small modification to customize how far the counter extends into the margin but you should move your question to the ConTeXt list to get it added to ConTeXt.

Comment: One could probably do `\setuplabeltext[en][figure={\llap{Fig}ure }]`, but that might break something else, so I do not really suggest it.